# Python nested html tags with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, regex, beautifulsoup

i'm trying to get some all the href URLs from a nested html code:

```
...
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle wide-nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown">TEXT_1 <b class="caret"></b></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li class="class_A"><a title="Title_1" href="http://www.customurl_1.com">Title_1</a></li>
<li class="class_B"><a title="Title_2" href="http://www.customurl_2.com">Title_2</a></li>
...
<li class="class_A"><a title="Title_X" href="http://www.customurl_X.com">Title_X</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
...
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle wide-nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown">TEXT_2 <b class="caret"></b></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li class="class_A"><a title="Title_1" href="http://www.customurl_1.com">Title_1</a></li>
<li class="class_B"><a title="Title_2" href="http://www.customurl_2.com">Title_2</a></li>
...
<li class="class_A"><a title="Title_X" href="http://www.customurl_X.com">Title_X</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
...
```

In the original html code there are about 15 "li" blocks with class "dropdown", 
but i want to get only the URLs from the block with text = TEXT_1.
It's possible to grap all these nested urls with BeautifulSoup?

Thanks for the help

Comment: You shouldn't use a regex; use a [HTML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: I have already tried with regex and it works but the result is not fine.

Comment: Whatever floats your boat - you **can** use a regex, but you **shouldn't**.

Comment: Yes you can do what you want with BeautifulSoup, you should try it and come back if you get stuck.

Comment: You should use lxml that allows to query your html with XPath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example with lxml and Xpath:

```
from lxml import etree
from io import StringIO

parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree   = etree.parse(StringIO(html), parser)
hrefs = tree.xpath('//li[@class="dropdown" and a[starts-with(.,"TEXT_1")]]/ul[@class="dropdown-menu"]/li/a/@href')

print hrefs
```

Where `html` is a unicode string with your html content. Result:

```
['http://www.customurl_1.com', 'http://www.customurl_2.com', 'http://www.customurl_X.com']
```

Note: I use the `starts-with` function to be more precise in the XPath query, but you can use `contains` in a same way if `TEXT_1` is not always at the begining of the text node.

Query details:

```
//              # anywhere in the domtree
li              # a li tag with the following conditions:
[                               # (opening condition bracket for li)
    @class="dropdown"           # li has a class attribute equal to "dropdown" 
  and                           # and
    a                           # a child tag "a"
    [                           # (open a condition for "a")
        starts-with(.,"TEXT_1") # that the text starts with "TEXT_1"
    ]                           # (close a condition for "a")
]                               # (close the condition for li)
/                            # li's child (/ stands for immediate descendant)
ul[@class="dropdown-menu"]   # "ul" with class equal to "dropdown-menu"
/li                          # "li" children of "ul"
/a                           # "a" children of "li"
/@href                       # href attributes children of "a"
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilst not as elegant as Xpath, you can always write the logic using everyday Python iteration. BeautifulSoup allows passing a function as a filter to `find_all` in situations when you have a complex case such as this one.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """<html>..."""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)

def matches_block(tag):
    return matches_dropdown(tag) and tag.find(matches_text) != None

def matches_dropdown(tag):
    return tag.name == 'li' and tag.has_attr('class') and 'dropdown' in tag['class']

def matches_text(tag):
    return tag.name == 'a' and tag.get_text().startswith('TEXT_1')

for li in soup.find_all(matches_block):
    for ul in li.find_all('ul', class_='dropdown-menu'):
        for a in ul.find_all('a'):
            if a.has_attr('href'):
                print (a['href'])
```